# In liquibase, How to have a unique changelog usable on multiple schema

Tags: liquibase

Liquibase ask for fully defined schema Name, for example for the indexExists tag. But what if want to run a changeset on multiple schema. Is there a way to indicate running on the current schema, or to dynamically set it when running an update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad, that schemaName is not a required attribute for createIndex.